# Postfix Outgoing Mail Suddenly Being Deferred

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am having trouble sending mail with postfix after changing the "Format for usernames that include domain" under the "Mail For Domain" template. Basically I had everything working but then changed the default usernames from being `user.domain` to `user@domain.co`, then deleted and recreated my email accounts (including associated files in home directory) under that new format. Once this was done, I was unable to send any email, either from accounts that I'd recreated or from brand new accounts. I restoring the previous template settings and recreating the accounts and that didn't work either.

Below is an example of what comes up in `/var/log/mail.log` when I attempt to send an email.

```
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/smtpd[11772]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/smtpd[11772]: 691B9138176E: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/cleanup[11775]: 691B9138176E: message-id=<1405537337.11762@domain.co>
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/smtpd[11772]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/qmgr[10765]: 691B9138176E: from=<user@domain.co>, size=666, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/qmgr[10765]: warning: connect to transport private/sam-domain.co: No such file or directory
Jul 16 19:02:17 host postfix/error[11735]: 691B9138176E: to=<recipient@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

Also, here's my `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = domain.co, localhost.domain.co, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your `master.cf`.

Comment: You need the master.cf and your mapping files as well.  You have a mapping issue - it's fairly visible in the first error message.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys.  I found a solution though, which I will post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a [response](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/33725#comment-134700) on the Virtualmin forum that worked like a charm.

In summary, the issue was indeed in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, as was suggested by the folks above.  I ended up commenting out the following line:

```
#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

did a `service postfix restart` and now my email works perfectly.

Thanks for the comments above and hope this might help someone in the future.